# Bash Parameter Substitution In Arrays and Loops

Tags: arrays, bash

New Bash user here. I'm trying to download a ton of grib2 files from slightly different URLs to plot data from weather models. To do this, I'm trying to simulate a nested array (since bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays) using a nested for loop, with the "outer" array describing the level of a certain atmospheric variable and the "inner" arrays describing the atmospheric variables at that level.

My first problem is with declaring the arrays describing the atmospheric variables. When I call "echo ${VAR${LEV[0]}}", I get a "bad substitution" error.

```
declare -a LEV=("500_mb" "300_mb")
eval "declare -a VAR${LEV[0]}=("hgt" "abs" "ugrd" "vgrd")"
eval "declare -a VAR${LEV[1]}=("hgt" "tmp" "ugrd" "vgrd")"
```

I have a similar problem in my nested for loop and get a "bad substitution" error at ${#VAR${LEV[i]}[@]}.

```
for ((i=0;i<${#LEV[@]};i++)); do
        for ((j=0;j<${#VAR${LEV[i]}[@]};j++)) do
            GRIBFILE="/home/mint/opengrads/Contents/gribfiles/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}_${FORECASTHOUR}_${LEV[i]}_${VAR[j]}"
            CTLFILE="/home/mint/opengrads/Contents/controlfiles/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}_${FORECASTHOUR}_${LEV[i]}_${VAR[j]}.ctl"
            URL="http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t${INITHOUR}z.pgrb2.0p25.f${FORECASTHOUR}&lev_${LEV[i]}=on&var_${VAR[j]}=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}"  
            wget -O $GRIBFILE $URL 
            create_control $GRIBFILE $CTLFILE
        done
   done
```

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to fix these errors or can suggest a better way to achieve the desired means of elegantly downloading all these files.

Thank you!

Comment: You're better off using a language like python for this. Bash is not well suited to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always simulate a two-dimension array using a one-dimension array, for example:

```
rows=3
cols=5
arr=(
    a b c d e
    f g h i j
    k l m n o
)

for ((i = 0; i < rows; i++)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < cols; j++)); do
        ((index = i * cols + j))
        printf "%s " ${arr[index]}
    done
    echo
done
```

This prints:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

Even though `arr` is one-dimensional.
The key is calculating `index` based on `i`, `j` and the number of columns per row.

If your two-dimensional array is ragged (not all rows have the same column),
then you could use a designated dummy value that should be skipped,
for example:

```
rows=3
cols=5
d=-
arr=(
    a b c d  e
    f g h $d $d
    k l m n  $d
)

for ((i = 0; i < rows; i++)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < cols; j++)); do
        ((index = i * cols + j))
        [[ ${arr[index]} != "$d" ]] || continue
        printf "%s " ${arr[index]}
    done
    echo
done
```

Prints:

```
a b c d e
f g h
k l m n
```

Based on the above, and with some other improvements, you could rewrite your script like this:

```
LEV=(500_mb 300_mb)
VAR=(
  hgt abs ugrd vgrd
  hgt tmp ugrd vgrd
)
rows=2
cols=4

for ((i = 0; i < rows; i++)); do
    for ((j = 0; j < cols; j++)); do
        ((index = i * cols + j))
        GRIBFILE="/home/mint/opengrads/Contents/gribfiles/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}_${FORECASTHOUR}_${LEV[i]}_${VAR[index]}"
        CTLFILE="/home/mint/opengrads/Contents/controlfiles/${MODEL}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}/${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}_${FORECASTHOUR}_${LEV[i]}_${VAR[index]}.ctl"
        URL="http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25.pl?file=gfs.t${INITHOUR}z.pgrb2.0p25.f${FORECASTHOUR}&lev_${LEV[i]}=on&var_${VAR[index]}=on&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fgfs.${INIT_INTDATE}${INITHOUR}"  
        wget -O $GRIBFILE $URL 
        create_control $GRIBFILE $CTLFILE
    done
done
```